# Connecting JFrame to JPanel using JButton, Problems with JTextFields

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

My problem is making my Main class and Journal class connect together, in the Main class users will input two variables and click the button to create the table, in the Journal class, it will take the two variables and make it go through a process before they get added into the table so i need JTextField1 as variable a and JTextField2 as variable b.

I used netbeans to create the Main class and my own methods to create the table class please help! Thanks! This is the part of the Main class Netbeans tells me to edit when I right click > Events > Action > Action Performed

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     int data1 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
     int data2 = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());

}
```

Here is my Code:

```
package Components;

/**
 *
 * @author dustinpx2014
 */

import java.awt.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
public class Journal extends JPanel
{
    private JTable table;
    private int a;//Number of Students
    private int b;// Length of Trip
    public Journal() 
    {

        String colN1 = "Date";
        String colN2 = "Student"; 

        int c = a*2/b; // Determining # of Journals
        int col = c*2; // Creating two columns for every journal(Day and Student)
        String[] columnNames = new String[col]; //For Loop: inserting column names
        for(int colF = 0; colF < col; colF++)
        {
            if(colF%2 == 0)
            {
                columnNames[colF] = colN1;
            }
            else
            {
                columnNames[colF] = colN2;
            }
        }
        int row = b; //row = number of days
        int d = 1; //day number
        int s = 1; //student number
        int x = 0; //counter for the # of times students write
        int z = 1; // student number(no limit)
        int z1 = a/2; // student number 2
        int x1 = 0; // counter for the # of times students write 2
        int x2 = 0;
        int w = 1;
        Object[][] data = new Object[row][col];

        for (int col1 = 0; col1 < data[0].length; col1++)
        {
            for (int row1 = 0; row1<data.length; row1++)//goes through the table by column
            {
                if(d > b) //reseting the date
                {
                    d = 1;
                }
                if(s > a && x <= 2) //reseting student number and adds count
                {
                    s = 1;
                    x++;
                }
                if(z > a)
                {
                    z = 1;
                }
                if(z1 > a && x1 <= 2)
                {
                    z1 = 1;
                    x1++;
                }
                if (w>a)
                {
                    w++;
                }
                if(col1%2 == 0) //inserts the day
                {
                    data[row1][col1]= "Day " + d;
                    d++;
                }
                else if (s!=data[row1][col1])//inserts student number
                {
                    data[row1][col1]= s;
                    s++;
                    z++;
                    w++;
                }
                for (int col2 = 1; col2 < data[0].length; col2++)
                {
                    for (int row2 = 0; row2<data.length; row2++)//goes through the table by column
                    {
                        if(z == data[row2][col2] && col2%2!=0)//checks for repeats and replaces them
                        {

                            for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) //checking all columns
                            {
                                if (z1 == a/2 && x1 <= 5) //adds count
                                {
                                    x1++;
                                }
                                else if(z1 > a && x1 <= 5)
                                {
                                    z1 = 1;
                                    x1++;

                                }
                                if(z == data[row2][y])
                                {
                                    data[row2][col2] = z1;
                                    z1++;
                                    w++;
                                }

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                for (int row3 = 1; row3 < data.length; row3++)
                {
                    for (int col3 = 0; col3<data[0].length; col3++)//goes through the table by rows
                    {
                        if(w == data[row3][col3] && col3%2!=0)//checks for repeats and replaces them
                        {
                            for(int y2 = 0; y2 < col; y2++)
                            {
                                if(
                                row3<row-1 && 
                                row3> 1 && 
                                w==data[row3+1][y2] && 
                                w==data[row3-1][y2] &&
                                w==data[row3][y2]
                                ) //checks rows
                                {
                                    data[row3][col3] = 0;

                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        JTable table = new JTable(data, columnNames);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(table.getPreferredSize());
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);
        add(scrollPane);
    }

    public JTable getTable() {
        return table;
    }

    private static void gui()
    {
        JFrame gui = new JFrame();
        gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        gui.setTitle("Journal List");
        gui.setSize(700,200);
        gui.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        gui.setVisible(true);
        gui.add(new Journal());
    }


}
```

Please help add anything or delete anything in my code to make them work, THANK YOU :)

Comment: your problem are not so clear try to explain more

Comment: I need to have the JButton open the JTable in the Journal class and transfer the ints in the JTextFields to the variables a and b in the Journal Class

Comment: what do you mean by open JTable  jtable is like nourmal table do you mean to create JTable give an example

Comment: When the JButton is clicked the table should open up and be arranged according to the variables taken from the JTextField

Comment: wow that is not programming that is juggling :) joking only

Comment: I have two classes Main with JTextFields and Jbutton and Journal with a Jtable extending JPanel. I need to use the Main class to operate the Journal class how do you use JButton to open up the JPanel and how do you use the variables in JTextField and apply them to variables a and b?

Comment: Please do not ask two questions that are the same.

Answer (score 0):

write that over your constrictor

```
public static void main(String args[]){
Journal is= new Journal();


}
public Journal() 
{...}
```